# Merging multiple .ics file into one containing all events

Tags: r, merge, calendar

my question:

I have 10 file .ics created with R, each referring to an event.
My goal is to set only ONE file .ics that includes all 10 events

I am using R Versione 2023.12.1+402 (2023.12.1+402)

Any idea?

thanks!

Ale

I asked Chat-gpt, but it failed to give me any effective solution.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Where you got stuck? Have you tried [{calendar}](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/calendar/html/00Index.html) package?